# Mathematica equivalent of Ruby's inject

Tags: functional-programming, wolfram-mathematica

Is there a Mathematica function like `inject` in Ruby? For example, if I want the product of the elements in a list, in Ruby I can write:

```
list.inject(1) { |prod,el| prod * el }
```

I found I can just use `Product` in Mathematica:

```
Apply[Product, list]
```

However, this isn't general enough for me (like, if I don't just want the product or sum of the numbers). What's the closest equivalent to `inject`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The equivalent is [Fold](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fold.html).
I think this is more typically called "reduce" -- that's the Python name anyway.

Translating your example:

```
Fold[#1*#2&, 1, list]
```

That `#1*#2&` is a binary lambda function that multiplies its arguments.
In this case you could just use `Times` instead:

```
Fold[Times, 1, list]
```

Or of course just apply `Times` to the list:

```
Apply[Times, list]
```

Or, for short:

```
Times @@ list
```

NOTE: The version in your question where you use Product instead of Times will not work.
[Product](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Product.html) is for something else, namely the analog of [Sum](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sum.html).

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I was writing from memory and I meant to say `Times`.

Comment: 'I think this is more typically called "reduce"'. I'd say the name fold is at least as common as reduce. The wikipedia page for the fold function lists 10 languages that call it fold and 8 that call it reduce. Also note that "Reduce (higher-order function)" redirects to "Fold (higher-order function)".